# Start Recording for Microsoft Coded UI Test 2017 is not selectable

Tags: visual-studio-2017, coded-ui-tests

I am just begining to learn about Coded UI test. Since it is still 2017, I figure Visual Studio 2017 is the best version I can try. Having a Visual Studio Enterprise license I decided to try it out. Turns out I have it installed even. Great. There are lots of tutorials that all seem to start the same way:

1. Start a new coded UI test builder project in Visual Studio.
2. generate coded ui test using test builder.

When the test builder pops up, most of the buttons on the tool including the record button are not selectable. There must be a configuration issue or a problem with my proceedure. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that there are other answers to this question, but one resolution to the issue seems to be that I origionally launched the project by selecting Coded UI test project from the installed node of the tree view for launching a project... When I launched a new project from the C# language sub node, then it worked. This seems like a bug to me. Now when I try to repeat launching a new project from the installed node nothing happens.

So now that I select the selectable recording button it tells me to restart the computer. Thats fine... OK: it appears to be working.